# How do you plot with multiple colours for the same point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data that I have clustered, and wish to compare it to human-annotations of the same data. The problem I have is that the human-annotator has marked some of the points to have co-existing events (i.e. some points in the space would have two or more labels associated with them). Is there a way that I can show this using matplotlib?

I am thinking something along the lines of the following simplified example:
[image]

The main point is to **not** have the points with events 1 & 2 be classified as some new event '3', but instead to plot the points that have two events, to display these events independently. I assume that this is not an easy task, as there could potentially be more than two coexisting events, but for this example I am only focussing on two.

---

My plan was to create a one-hot array of shape=(n_points, n_events), and linearly selecting colours for a colourmap by using plt.cm.rainbow which would represent each unique event. But I have gotten stuck here as I do not know how to plot the points with >1 label.

The style in which the points are plotted does not strictly matter (i.e. having the side-by-side colours as I have illustrated is not a requirement), any method of displaying them should be adequate so long as points with multiple events are easily identifiable.

I would post my attempt so far, but as I am stuck on such an early step, it only goes as far as generating a random toy dataset of shape (20, 2), and creating the one-hot array of labels as I had previously mentioned.

Comment: check out color and fill in ggplot or plotnine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `color` as well as `markerfacecoloralt` together with `fillstyle='left'` in order to obtain a side-by-side color plot. For more information and other styles see [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.sort(np.random.random(size=20))
y = x + np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=x.shape)

i, j = len(x)//2 - 2, len(x)//2 + 3  # separate the points in left and right

colors = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x[:i], y[:i], 'o', color=colors[0], ms=15)  # left part
ax.plot(x[j:], y[j:], 'o', color=colors[1], ms=15)  # right part
ax.plot(x[i:j], y[i:j], 'o',                        # middle part
        fillstyle='left', color=colors[0], markerfacecoloralt=colors[1], ms=15)

plt.show()
```

Example plot:

[image: Example]

Comment: You can add another kwarg "markeredgewidth=0" or in short "mew=0" to remove the blue edge on the mixed colour points (and on the others to give them all the same size)

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! It'll of course have to be slightly adapted to fit my code, but that is simple & unrelated to this question. Your other answer was equally good, but I've marked this one as the accepted answer as it relates more directly to my question.

Comment: @JanKuiken This is also a helpful tip, thank you too!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require side-by-side colors you could plot two points on top of each other, using different sizes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.sort(np.random.random(size=20))
y = x + np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=x.shape)

i, j = len(x)//2 - 2, len(x)//2 + 3  # separate the points in left and right

colors = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x[:j], y[:j], c=colors[0], s=100)  # left part (including middle)
ax.scatter(x[j:], y[j:], c=colors[1], s=100)  # right part
ax.scatter(x[i:j], y[i:j], c=colors[1], s=20)  # middle part (using smaller size)

plt.show()
```

Example plot:

[image: Example]